# Using python pandas how can I select matched pairs to perform a matched-pair student's t-test?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I am trying to perform a matched pairs student's t-test `scipy.stats.ttest_rel` and am having a difficult time removing "non-duplicate" values.

Here is the simplest example I could come up with:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sample': ['H1', 'H1', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H3'],
    'L/R': ['L', 'L', 'R', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
    'Region': ['Eq', 'Po', 'Eq', 'Po', 'Eq', 'Po'], 
    'MatchedPair': ['H1L', 'H1L', 'H1R', 'H2L', 'H2L', 'H3L'], 
    'Value': [12.2, 11.1, 14.5, 9.0, 10.2, 11.6]
})
```

When printed out:

```py
df
Out[236]: 
  Sample L/R Region MatchedPair  Value
0     H1   L     Eq         H1L   12.2
1     H1   L     Po         H1L   11.1
2     H1   R     Eq         H1R   14.5
3     H2   L     Po         H2L    9.0
4     H2   L     Eq         H2L   10.2
5     H3   L     Po         H3L   11.6
```

I'm trying to compare matched pairs (Region L & R by Sample) so because I don't have a data point for H2R I have unequal length arrays.

The goal is to do this:

```py
f, p = stats.ttest_rel(dfMP['Value'][df['Region'] == 'Eq'], 
                       dfMP['Value'][df['Region'] == 'Po'])
```

Where `dfMP` is the dataframe that contains matched pairs and excludes non-matched pairs based on the Sample column so I can compare Region ('Eq', vs 'Po' within the MatchedPair column).

Right now I can only do this:

```py
f, p = stats.ttest_ind(df['Value'][df['Region'] == 'Eq'], 
                       df['Value'][df['Region'] == 'Po'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with after using the pandas `duplicated` function:

```py
dfMP = df[df.duplicated(['MatchedPair'], keep=False)]
f, p = stats.ttest_rel(dfMP['Value'][dfMP['Region'] == 'Eq'], 
                       dfMP['Value'][dfMP['Region'] == 'Po'])

print(f, p, "Matched Pairs Student's t-test")

f, p = stats.ttest_ind(dfMP['Value'][dfMP['Region'] == 'Eq'], 
                       dfMP['Value'][dfMP['Region'] == 'Po'])

print(f, p, "Student's t-test")
```

Print-out:

```py
23.00000000000007 0.027661699133323864 Matched Pairs Student's t-test
0.7931034482758611 0.5108596784320201 Student's t-test
```

I believe this should work, but am unsure if the `duplicated` method is the correct approach.